# How to send a request to Pgpool2 server from php script?

Tags: docker, postgresql, cluster, php7

Actualy i'm trying to create a postgres replication system using pgpool2 and docker containers, I created 2 containers running postgres and another container for pgpool2, so when I tried to connect to pgpool2 server through php script I got the following error :

> pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with *Docker* before... but...

In most default configurations, postgresql does not allow non-local connections.  In order to allow remote connections, you will need to add a 'host' line in your pg_hba.conf file.

Usually that file is somewhere like:

```
/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf
```

Something like this:

```
#TYPE   DATABASE     USER         ADDRESS      AUTH METHOD
host    database1    user1     192.168.1.0/24      md5
```

Then restart your postgresql cluster, via /etc/init.d/postgresql restart or whatever is appropriate for your OS.

You should be able to see the open port on your remote host, via:

```
netstat -l
```

If you've done it correctly, the addresses should change from 'localhost' to 0.0.0.0 .

You will also need to add 'user1' as a postgresql user with a password and create a database for that user to play in.

This can be accomplished by becoming the postgresql superuser via something like this:

```
sudo -s
#su postgres
postgres@host$ createuser user1 -P
     enter in a password
postgres@host$ createdb database1 -O user1
```

And then you should be able to connect to your remote postgresql cluster via a local command of:

```
psql -h remote.host.address -U user1 -d database1
```

Of course, all IP addresses are illustrative only.  Make changes as appropriate.